# Material-UI CardMedia not loading dynamic image from URL but works with static image

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, graphql, material-ui

I've written a function that returns image URLs best on the memType:

```
const renderPicture = (memType, memID) => {
    if ((memType === "Music")) {
        toString(memID.music.map((albumArt) => (albumArt.albumArt)))
    } else if ((memType === "Movie")) {
        toString(memID.movie.map((poster) => (poster.poster)))
    } else if ((memType === "TVShow")) {
        toString(memID.tvshow.map((poster) => (poster.poster)))
    } else if ((memType === "Game")) {
        toString(memID.game.map((boxArt) => (boxArt.boxArt)))
    } else if ((memType === "Event")) {
        return require('../img/historyHead.png')
    }
}
```

This is called by CardMedia when rendering the page:

```
<CardMedia
 className={classes.cardMedia}
 image={renderPicture(memID.memType, memID)}
 style={{ width: "100%", height: "150px" }}
/>
```

This works for the static images for `memType === 'Event'` but not for the other memTypes that are returning a URL. I believe it's something to do with `require` but can't work out the best way to include this.

CardMedia sits within a larger function that returns data from a GraphQL query:

```
const getMemsCard = (i) => {
    return data.Mem.map((memID, i) => (
        memID.mem.includes(filter) &&
        < Grid item xs={12} sm={4} lg={4} key={i} >
            <Card className={classes.card} onClick={() => history.push(`/mems/${memID.memID}`)}>
                <CardHeader className={classes.cardHeader}
                    avatar={
                        <Avatar aria-label="memory" className={classes.avatar}>
                            {renderAvatar(memID.memType)}
                        </Avatar>
                    }
                    action={
                        <span className={classes.emoji}>{memID.emoji}</span>
                    }
                    title={<span style={{ fontWeight: '550' }}>{memID.mem}</span>}
                    subheader={<span>{memID.date.day}-{memID.date.month}-{memID.date.year}</span>}
                />
                <CardMedia
                    className={classes.cardMedia}
                    image={renderPicture(memID.memType, memID)}
                    style={{ width: "100%", height: "150px" }}
                />
                <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                    <p>with {memID.person
                        .map((person, i, arr) => {
                            let divider = i < arr.length - 1 && <span>, </span>;
                            return (
                                <span key={i}>
                                    {person.nickname}
                                    {divider}
                                </span>
                            )
                        })}
                        <span> at</span> {memID.place
                            .map((place, i) => <span key={i}>{place.place}</span>)}</p>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Grid >
    ))
};
```

The GraphQL query is called as follows:

```
const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_MEM)
if (loading) return <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }} >Loading...</p>
if (error) return <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }} >Error</p>
```

The structure of the Graph QL query is as follows:

```
const GET_MEM = gql`
  {
    Mem(orderBy: date_asc) {
      memID
      mem
      date {
        day
        month
        year
      }
      memType
      emoji
      personID @skip(if: false)
      placeID @skip(if: false)
      person {
        nickname
      }
      place {
        place
      }
      music {
          albumArt
      }
      movie {
        poster
      }
      tvshow {
        poster
      }
      game {
          boxArt
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Below is some sample data:

```
"Mem": [
  {
    "memID": "180",
    "mem": "The Empire Strikes Back",
    "date": {
      "day": 20,
      "month": 5,
      "year": 1980
    },
    "memType": "Movie",
    "emoji": "",
    "personID": null,
    "placeID": null,
    "person": [],
    "place": [],
    "music": [],
    "movie": [
      {
        "poster": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original//7BuH8itoSrLExs2YZSsM01Qk2no.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "tvshow": [],
    "game": []
  },
```

Essentially, GraphQL queries a Neo4j graph database a brings back all nodes of type 'Mem' and also the image URLs from other nodes that have a relationship with 'Mem' nodes of type 'Person', 'Place', 'Music', 'Movie', 'TVShow' and 'Game'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling I've managed to solve this problem.

Firstly, I was using `toString()` incorrectly as it needs to come after the array as `.toString()`.

Secondly, I needed to add a return to each of the if statements.

Lastly, I needed to remove `require` from the if statement as this works for static internal images but not for external urls.

My final code is as follows:

```
const renderPicture = (memType, memID) => {
    if ((memType === "Music")) {
        return ((memID.music.map((albumArt) => (albumArt.albumArt))).toString())
    } else if ((memType === "Movie")) {
        return ((memID.movie.map((poster) => (poster.poster))).toString())
    } else if ((memType === "TVShow")) {
        return ((memID.tvshow.map((poster) => (poster.poster))).toString())
    } else if ((memType === "Game")) {
        return ((memID.game.map((boxArt) => (boxArt.boxArt))).toString())
    } else if ((memType === "Event")) {
        return require('../../img/historyHead.png')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `image` prop of `CardMedia` requires a string prop. But you are passing an array to `image` because `.map()` function return an array.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I've added toString (amended in the question too) but the images are still not rendering as I think `require` needs to be included as well

Comment: @Sean What is ```.map()``` using for? Can you add  ```memID``` data to your post?

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I've added some more details to the post - `.map()` is for iterating through an array of `Mem` data which comes from a GraphQL query.

Comment: @Sean Plz show me the data that 's retrieved from ```GET_MEM``` query? I wonder why you use ```.map()``` in ```renderPicture ``` to generate image url.

Comment: Hi Michael, I've added some sample data above. I use `.map()` as the image URLs are contained within an array. Thanks for taking the time to look at this.